# Is it possible via .htaccess to allow a single URL on my site to be accessed / embedded in an iframe?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iframe, x-frame-options

I just have one or two URLs which need to be able to accessed on any remote domain via iframe. I am researching X-Frame-Options but it seems you can only allow from specific domains.

Comment: I *think* that the `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors *` header for the allowed file should do the trick. I can't test it though, so I don't really want to post it as an answer just yet. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Using_Content_Security_Policy), [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).